# How to check if array that inside an object contains element mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hi i have this document :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62792b4a0c9c5a00b6a8e17b"),
    "username" : "user_1",
    "words" : [ 
        {
            "word" : "RATIONAL",
            "subwords" : [ 
                "RAT", 
                "TAN"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "word" : "YOUNGER",
            "subwords" : [ 
                "YOU", 
                "YOUR"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find a document that has a specific `word` for example "RATIONAL" and his `subwords` array contains an element.

for example i want to check if there is a document that has:
username:"user_1
in his `words` array he contains the `word`:"RATIONAL"
and his `subwords` array contains the `word` "RAT"

something like that:

```
db.users.find({username:"user_1","words":{word:"RATIONAL",subword:"RAT"}}).pretty();
```

thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
db.users.find({"username": "user_1", "words.word": "RATIONAL", "words.subwords": "RAT"})
```

You also could use the The `$elemMatch` operator:

```
db.users.find({"username": "user_1",  "words": { "$elemMatch": { "word": "RATIONAL", "subwords": "RAT" } }})
```

Comment: I have a weird problem when im trying this on mongoDB shell the query works, but when i try it on Nodejs it return me the document based only if the username match or not.

Comment: @TalLevi Share the query

Comment: const user =  await users.find({"username": "user_1",  words: { "$elemMatch": { word: "RATIONAL", subwords: "RAT" } }})

Comment: @TalLevi It will better if you create new question with the problem you are having in NodeJS the environment you are using, orm, etc..

Comment: @TalLevi in that case what it the data returned? Null? Array?

Comment: Problem solved i had a problem with the schema thank you very much